# How to automate point-in-polygon queries in ArcView?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, python, polygon, point

Layer1 = point shapefile (multiple points, geocoded)

Layer2 = polygon (1 attribute; (1,2,3...))

I want a non-gis person to be able input a single address and be told the attribute of the polygon which it falls within.

What is the simplest way to accomplish this?

The user will be doing this in arcview.  I use ArcInfo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the points are already geocoded, it seems like you could just pre-process the point data using a [Spatial Join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000.htm) and add that polygon attributes to the point features.

From Arc10 help: "*Joins attributes from one feature class to another based on a spatial relationship. The target features and the joined attributes from the join features are written to the output feature class*."

If you preprocess the data this way, you could still use ArcReader to display the data for the user as an attribute via teh Identify tool.

Answer (score 0):

Something Google turned up that might be useful/bad news: http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=113&f=1142&t=139492

Sounds like there is no geocoding capability in ArcReader. Have you considered having your users use [ArcGIS Explorer](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer/index.html) instead?

Comment: The addresses are already geocoded and sit as a point shapefile layer in arcreader.

Comment: I see. It seems the extent of [customization in ArcReader](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Customizing_ArcReader/000s0000001q000000/) is authoring template files. Additionally there is no Python/arcpy support in ArcReader. If you must use ArcReader I think all you can do is explain how to use the included tools to accomplish this task.

Comment: Ok.  The user is now able to use arcview now, with a bit of negotiating :)

Comment: Cool. Which version of ArcGIS Desktop are they using? (9.3 or 10 specifically)?

Comment: They are using ARCGIS 10